# Changing the stroke from black to white on changing background in SVG files

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG file which is drawn on a white background.

If the user selects to display on a black background, then all the paths rendered as black disappear.

Is it possible to change all elements in the SVG file which are rendered in black so that they render in white? Including paths, text, etc.

The SVG is viewed in the Browser, so if this could be accomplished in CSS and javascript, I'd like to do it that way.

Sorry: There are 256 colours in the SVG.

I have made up a test svg as follows:

```
<svg
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="fgc">
      <stop stop-color="blue"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="layer1" >
    <rect
       style="stroke:url(#fgc);fill: none;"
       id="rect10"
       width="110"
       height="75"
       x="50"
       y="55" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I am calling this from the HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="application/x-javascript">
var drg="";
var svgDoc="";
var svgItem="";
window.onload=function() {
    drg = document.getElementById("drawing");
    svgDoc = drg.contentDocument;
    svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById("fgc");
    console.log(svgItem.getAttribute("stop-color"));
    svgItem.setAttribute("stop-color", "red");
    console.log(svgItem.getAttribute("stop-color"));
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<object id="drawing" data="drawing.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="200" height="150"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

The console.log(svgItem.getAttribute("stop-color")) prints "null" in the browser console prior to the svgItem.setAttribute("stop-color", "red") and "red" after it.

The rectangle is rendered blue.

Clearly changing the 'stop-color' attribute to red in the window.onload won't work because the svg graphic is already loaded. How do I set up my graphic up to render in red prior to loading?

Also, I'm expecting console.log(svgItem.getAttribute("stop-color")) to give me 'blue' prior to the change, but it gives me 'null' which must mean I'm changing the wrong attribute.

Comment: Would you further elaborate on the SVG requirements?  Specifically, is the color palette limited to white or do other colors exist?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.

> If the user selects to display on a black background, then all the
>   paths rendered as black disappear.

When user change the background add a class to the parent of the svg like `bg-black` . Remove this class when user changes the background to white.

In CSS you change the color like this.

```
.bg-black svg path,
.bg-black svg circle {
  stroke: white !important;
}
.bg-black svg text {
  fill: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I take it I call the svg file in the HTML `<svg class="bg-black" xlink:href="17_425.svg" />`? Does this change all colours to white, though?

Comment: I doubt if my code works with svg loaded via xlink:href !

Comment: Okay, how would you implement it? I suspect that your code would change all stroke colours to white. Is this the case? Is it possible to redefine 'black' to another colour? If I used 'fgcolour' instead of 'black', could I define the value of 'fgcolour' through css?